# How to merge two subversion repositories using svnadmin

Tags: svn, merge, repository

How to merge two subversion (1.6) repositories on Debian Wheezy assuming the following repository layout:

```
reposA
    +-trunk
        +-project-1
        +-project-2
        +-project-3
    +-tags
        +-project-1
    +-branches
        +-project-1

reposB
    +-trunk
        +-project-4
        +-project-5
        +-project-6
    +-tags
        +-project-4
    +-branches
        +-project-4
```

Target layout should look like this:

```
reposAB
        +-trunk
            +-project-1
            +-project-2
            +-project-3
            +-project-4
            +-project-5
            +-project-6
        +-tags
            +-...
        +-branches
            +-...
```

What I already tried is:

```
svnadmin dump reposA > reposA.dmp 
svnadmin dump reposB > reposB.dmp
svnadmin create new_common_repos
svnadmin load new_common_repo < reposA.dmp 
svnadmin load new_common_repo < reposB.dmp
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can load two dump to separate sub folders and then rearrange as you like:

```
svnadmin create new_common_repo
svn mkdir file:///path/to/new_common/repo/reposA -m "Created folder reposA"
svnadmin dump reposA | svnadmin load new_common_repo --parent-dir reposA
svn mkdir file:///path/to/new_common/repo/reposB -m "Created folder reposB"
svnadmin dump reposB | svnadmin load new_common_repo --parent-dir reposB
```

And then for each project:

```
svn mkdir file:///path/to/new_common/repo/trunk -m "Created folder trunk"
svn mv file:///path/to/new_common/repo/reposA/project-1  file:///path/to/new_common/repo/trunk/project-1
```

Comment: using svnadmin dump / load worked for me. Moving lots of projects within the newly created repository to different locations worked best using TrotoiseSVN client